# Quel est le meilleur terme français pour parler d'un « wireframe » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Je cherche à traduire *wireframe*, dans le contexte de la conception d'interface utilisateur.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je pense à [*esquisse*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esquisse), qui est un terme utilisé en particulier en peinture et en architecture. Je ne sais pas exactement à quoi correspond un *wireframe* dans le cas de la conception d'UI, mais c'est peut être un substitut adéquat, même s'il n'est pas forcément standard.

[Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/wireframe.html) donne *maquette* qui pourrait convenir tout aussi bien, et dans une moindre mesure, *armature* ou *représentation fil de fer*, qui sont des traductions plus courantes.

Comment: On m'avait suggéré _maquette_ ailleurs, mais j'aime bien _esquisse_, qui pour moi souligne encore plus que le concept n'est pas final.

Answer (score 7):

Dans le cadre de l'infographie 3D, où`on utilise des représentations "wireframe" on utilise le terme français de représentation en fil de fer.

La même chose s'apllique au design: [maquette en fil de fer](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireframe_%28design%29) ou simplement "wireframe design" en adoptant le vocabulaire anglais.
On peut aussi utiliser le terme de "prototypage", mais cela n'est pas exclusif au wireframe. Dans le même style il y a croquis, esquisse, maquette.

Comment: On comprend bien le rendu *fil de fer* pour la 3D. De ce que je comprends, c'est le sens originel qui a été généralisé (au sens : ébauche faite en omettant les détails) à d'autre discipline, car, a priori, un dessin ou une interface graphique en "fil de fer" n'as pas vraiment de sens.

Answer (score 4):

Je proposerais d après la lecture en fin de message

Sketch = croquis / esquisse

Wireframe = armature / maquette fil de fer

Mockups = maquette dans le sens design pas forcément d interaction mais une vraie idée du "look and feel"

Prototype = maquette fonctionnelle dans le cas d une techno Html pages conçues avec des liens qui fonctionnent.

http://52weeksofux.com/tagged/week_36

Answer (score 1):

Je suis étudiante dans ce domaine et j'utilise directement le mot *wireframe* sans traduction. Aucune personne dans mon entourage universitaire et professionnel n'ignore de quoi il s'agit. Un francophone, s'il s'y connait un peu, te comprendra donc très bien avec ce mot.

Toutefois si tu tiens à le traduire alors je te suggère le terme de *maquette fonctionnelle* qu'il est également assez courant de rencontrer.

Answer (score 0):

On pourrait aussi employer le mot **ébauche** comme le propose l'[OQLF](http://granddictionnaire.com).

Comment: Pouvez-vous svp préciser quelle entrée au GDT ? J'ai plutôt trouvé [_maquette conceptuelle_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529188) etc. Merci.